# How to open application with custom URI scheme?

Tags: android, custom-url

I have viewed different posts before asking to question but none of them solve my issue.

I want to open application with custom URI scheme : myapp://

I have tried `intent.setData(Uri.parse("myapp://"))` but it is not working.

So am i missing  anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("myapp://path"))

<activity android:name=".YourActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="path" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I also tried that in my sample application.not working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should define proper `intent-filter` in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data
                    android:host="browse"
                    android:pathPrefix=""
                    android:scheme="myapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

then in your Java code handle this intent:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
    List<String> segments = getIntent().getData().getPathSegments();
    String section = getIntent().getData().getHost();
    if (segments.size() > 1 && segments.get(0).equals("browse")) {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: this is my intent filter: `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.ACTION.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="temp" android:host="sample"/>
            </intent-filter>`

Comment: Then use intent.setData(Uri.parse("temp://sample"))

Comment: I added the java code sample so you can handle it in your java code @dreamcoder

Comment: I have tried  `intent.setData(Uri.parse("temp://sample"))`. Is it necessary to  handle the intent just to open activity?

Comment: Also try this: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("temp://sample"));